# Python indexing larger than range but does not output an error

Tags: python, list, indexing

so I have a list x = [1,2,3]

when I run
print(x[0:100])

it still prints out 1,2,3 I would expect an index out of range error.

Comment: Slicing does not throw an error for indexes that are out of range. Sometimes this can be used for good. For example, if you want to check if a string begins with a particular letter, `x[0]` gives an error if `x` contains no characters, but `x[0:1]` doesn't.

Comment: @Lucas Styles answered already, but here's a simple reference in future about slicing in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/14715054

Comment: It is the same for lists as for any other sequence type.

Answer (score 1):

It is just returning every element in the list up to 100. It doesn't require that there are 100 elements in the list. If you did x[100] it would error